# How to handle lists and atomic types in one j expression with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have difficulties in `data.table` when evaluating a `j` expression that contains lists AND atomic types

Look at the following example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
N=1e5
DT = data.table(x=sample(1:5,N,replace=T),
                y=sample(letters[1:5],N,replace=T),
                v=rnorm(N))
DT[,c(nbPoints=.N,as.list(quantile(v,probs = seq(0,1,.25)))),.(x,y)]
```

I can name the `nbPoints` by NOT the quintiles (`q%` is default naming).
I can I rename the quantiles `WITHIN` the `j` expression ?

```
    x y nbPoints        0%        25%           50%       75%     100%
 1: 2 d     4035 -4.218131 -0.6544560  0.0162812744 0.6851001 3.361237
 2: 3 b     3890 -3.619431 -0.6493404 -0.0030014514 0.6930898 3.566787
 3: 5 c     4055 -3.593988 -0.6718406 -0.0143884613 0.6464294 3.329382
```

I would have liked something like :
`DT[,c(nbPoints=.N,paste0('c',1:5)=as.list(quantile(v,probs = seq(0,1,.25)))),.(x,y)]`

to get

```
    x  y nbPoints        p1        p2           p3       p4     p5
 1: 2 d     4035 -4.218131 -0.6544560  0.0162812744 0.6851001 3.361237
 2: 3 b     3890 -3.619431 -0.6493404 -0.0030014514 0.6930898 3.566787
 3: 5 c     4055 -3.593988 -0.6718406 -0.0143884613 0.6464294 3.329382
```

But that's not working

Comment: `DT[,c(nbPoints=.N, setNames(as.list(quantile(v,probs = seq(0,1,.25))),LETTERS[1:5])),.(x,y)]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating new columns with `by`, following syntax `DT[i, j, by]`, `j` should evaluate to a list of columns. Their names are taken from `j` or assigned automatically where no name is found.

To assign names to a list, one can use `setNames`. In the OP's example:

```
DT[, c(
  nbPoints=.N,  
  setNames(
    as.list(quantile(v,probs = seq(0,1,.25))),
    LETTERS[1:5]
  )
), by=.(x,y)]
```

As @thelatemail suggested, you can instead name the full vector at once:

```
DT[, setNames( 
  c(list(.N), quantile(v,probs = seq(0,1,.25))), 
  c("nbPoints", LETTERS[1:5]) 
), by=.(x,y)]
```

`LETTERS[1:5]` can be swapped for other desired names. Fancier ways of assigning names are also available, like `setattr(L, "names", LETTERS[1:5])`, that will avoid copying of the list.

---

*Comment.* When constructing a list, [it is best to avoid coercing to one with `as.list`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts#4-dont-coerce-j-to-list-use-list-directly). I don't see a good way around it here, though.

Comment: `DT[,
  setNames(
    c(list(.N), quantile(v,probs = seq(0,1,.25))), 
    c("nbPoints", LETTERS[1:5])
  ),
  by=.(x,y)
]` maybe? Though it is probably doing the same coercion internally anyway.

Comment: @thelatemail Good idea. Thanks